# How may I pipe a timestamp to date and convert it to datetime?

Tags: bash, date, pipe

Assume we have a timestamp like below:

```
[xxxxxx ~]$ date -d@1530586185
Tue Jul  3 05:49:45 EEST 2018
```

and I want to pipe it to date like:

```
echo 1530586185 | date -d@
date: invalid date ‘@’   <-------- error message
```

How can I do it?

Comment: The question marked as duplicate does not handle the case of passing a timestamp (which needs the `@` and thus complicates things), so I think this question should be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion 1:

```
date -d"@$(echo 1530586185)"
```

Suggestion 2:

```
DATE=$(echo 1530586185); date -d"@$DATE"
```

Comment: I found the following way to do it  ```a=$(complicated command with pipes) ; date -d@$a``` to be the best